# Are there xenon compounds with two xenon atoms bonded directly to each other?

Tags: noble-gases

I've seen so many compounds containing xenon, and xenon was mostly the central atom, and if we had 2 xenons they would never bond directly to each other. I was curious if it is possible to have for example 2 xenons in a compound that are bonded directly to each other?

Comment: As you said yourself, we haven't seen any examples yet.

Comment: From a quick search, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7435756/ explains: "Noble gas (or aerogen) bond (NgB) can be outlined as the attractive interaction between an electron-rich atom or group of atoms and any element of Group-18 acting as an electron acceptor."

Answer (score 10):

One example is the $\ce{Xe2+}$ cation. Quoting from the abstract of [Formation of the dixenon cation, $\ce{Xe2+}$, in fluoroantimonate(V) media by oxidation–reduction methods: spectroscopic properties of the ion](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/c39780000502)

> A green species has been generated both by oxidation of gaseous xenon
> with a dioxygenyl salt and by reduction in antimony pentafluoride
> solution of the $\ce{XeF+}$ cation, e.g. with water or a suitable metal; the
> Raman, u.v.-visible and e.s.r. spectra of the product are all
> consistent with the identity $\ce{Xe2+}$, representing the first homonuclear
> noble-gas cation to be characterized in the condensed phases.